# Can't seem to disable .onBackPressed() in Fragments

Tags: android

I'm trying to disable the back button for all screens in my app (Fragments and Activites).

[image]

I'm able to successfully disable the back button in my MainActivity by simply removing the super method in `.onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //Disabled
}
```

The back button no longer works on this Activity screen.

However, once I have inflated a `DialogFragment`, the back button seems to work again, and once I click on it, it dismisses the inflated `DialogFragment`.

I am not sure why it's doing this, but after searching google I came accross this `onBackPressedDispatcher`

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher

I have tried the method in that doc which says to place this block of code inside my inflated `DialogFragment`

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container, false);
        
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(
                false
        ) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {

            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(
                this,
                callback);

        return view;
    }
```

However the back button is still working. I am not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

How can I disable the Android Back Button inside my `DialogFragment`?

**Edit:___________________________________________**

Calling `dialog.setCancelable()` does not work

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: `DialogFragment` has `onCreateDialog` method in which you can call `setCancelable(false)` on that dialog .. That should work i think..

Comment: calling ```dialog.setCancelable(false)``` does not work. But calling ```setCancelable(false)``` works!! Could you make a quick answer below so I can mark yours correct? Thanks for your help!!